# Dynamically generated table rows never update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET table I'm using to create a dynamic section of a form (the user can add multiple items with no limit). The table is defined in the markup of the page with the first row.

The code is along the lines of the following:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
row.Cells.Add(tc);
myTable.Rows.Add(row);
myTable.DataBind();
```

This works fine when I add the first row, but when I add subsequent rows, they never get added. It's like the table stops at the first addition and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show your code for adding more-than-one row?

Comment: Maybe that's the thing - the requirement is I add one row at a time on a button click...

Comment: It's because of postback.For dynamic created control you have to do the same thing in every postback i think